# What relationships should be looked for when asked to create a normalized Entity-Relationship diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

The following ER Diagram was constructed and asked to be Normalized. I was curious as to was er symbols one should pay attention to when normalizing a database model?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFIFL.png

Comment: Hi. What do *you* mean when you write "normalize"? Why aren't you doing what it says to do in your textbook or other reference you got that word & task from? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Eg for all of that diagram.

Answer (score 1):

In your tags, you have entity-relationship-model, and normalization, but not relational-model.  Strictly speaking, normalization pertains to the relational model of data, but not to the ER model of data.   ER diagrams are frequently used to depict either one of these two models,  or some kind of hybrid model that combines features of both ER and relational.

Your diagram appears to be a diagram of an ER model.  Consider the relationship "Must have/can have".  It has crows feet at both ends.  In a relational model, there would have to be another box, a junction box between the two entity boxes, to hold a table with two foreign keys.  In fact, there are no foreign keys in your diagram at all!  So it really looks like an ER model.

So what I'm going to say is that you have to convert this diagram from an ER model to a relational model, before you even think about normalization.  This may be the direct opposite of what your teacher is teaching you.  I can't help you with that.